# Events In Solana

Tags: transactions

Hello are there any events in Solana, like let's say if a Solana transfer has occurred and the transaction is yet to complete can we get an event at that moment kind of sounds stupid though! So is there any other way to get the data about the transaction that has just been confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

getTransaction() function returns transaction details for a confirmed transaction.

Parameters:  - transaction signature as base-58 encoded string

Results:

- {null} - if transaction is not found or not confirmed
- {object} - if the transaction is confirmed, an object with many
  fields like slot, block time,transaction , transaction status metadata
  etc.

For more reference checkout https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettransaction

Comment: thanks for the response. I was looking for some sort of logs and I got the functions. OnLogs and onProgramAccountChange that were my requirements. getTransaction would need the tx signature but these functions are better at providing logs since ant transaction that happens on our program is returned by these two methods accordingly.